# Паттерн хранитель

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Нам выдали задание на курсовую работу

У меня вот что

> Реализовать хранителя данных бортовых датчиков самолета. Запоминание производится при получении очередного сигнала от датчика, а также через некоторый интервал времени. Если за наблюдаемый период отклонений в показаниях датчика не было, обеспечить сжатие хранимой информации запоминания. Хранить записи в файле. Использовать шаблон «хранитель».

Почитала про этот паттерн. Но хороших примеров пока не нашла. Пока не пойму, как реализовать эти датчики и сам самолет..Какие функции доступны клиенту.

Может подскажете свои мысли?

Comment: Меня всегда радовали задания в стиле "написать квиксорт, используя указатели и операцию вычитания". Я обычно подходил к заданиям так:

    template<typename T>
    void quicksort(std::vector<T>& array)
    {
        // 1. take care of formal requirements
        {
            T* requiredPointer;
            int requiredSubtraction = 1 - 1;
        }

        // 2. now, the implementation
        ...
    }

Comment: Ну блин. Вам нужны объекты, представляющие самолёт и датчик. Датчики умеют, согласно вашему описанию -- что? Предоставляют значение по запросу и сигнализируют об изменениях (event?). Самолёт для вас просто хранитель коллекции датчиков. Затем, ваша логика подписывается на сообщения от датчиков и на таймер, и получает значения. Значения сбрасываются в файл с timestamp-ом. Если значение не поменялось, можно по идее не записывать (хотя тогда непонятно, нафига требование "через некоторый интервал времени"). Фсё?

---
Да, нужен ещё генератор fake-данных, которые будут как бы поступать с датчиков.

Comment: вот главный вопрос как раз с генератором как бы данных с датчиков..как его можно программно реализовать?

Comment: рандом все-таки думаете..
ну вполне может быть..
а тогда какие функции доступны пользователю этой программы? как думаете? просто программа запускается, работает сама по себе, записывает все показания..а пользователь что же? просто варианты использования никак не могу придумать для курсового (((

Comment: Ну, как вам хочется, а где именно проблема? Заводите таймер и в случайные моменты времени меняете значение на случайное из данного интервала.

---
Ну, если нет других данных, почему бы и не рандом? Или пусть научрук скажет, откуда брать фейковые данные, вдруг у него своё видение.

А пользователь что, пусть сидит и [фтыкает на лампочки](http://www.jargon.net/jargonfile/b/blinkenlights.html). Можете для прикола визуализировать показания датчиков цветными лампочками, но строго говоря это нафиг не нужно.

Comment: @VladD, ну с самолетом такое простое решение (изменение показателя на случайное из заданного диапазона) не пройдет. 

Может только температура тела пилота?

Понятно, что показатели высоты полета и давления за бортом тесно связаны. 

Скорость, расход топлива, высота, крен, тангаж, ускорения и т.п. (многие параметры) не являются независимыми.

Comment: омм..ну ладно..))
завтра постараюсь прояснить ситуацию у преподавателя..

Comment: @avp: Это уже дизайн предметной области, пусть научрук предоставляет данные и алгоритмы, к программированию строго говоря не относится. Без них рандом для первой реализации вполне покатит. Надо, понятно, сделать заменяемые/конфигурируемые реализации датчиков, чтобы можно было потом подменить, если что. Ну и на определённом этапе развития проекта датчики будут таки общаться с реальным железом, конечно.

Comment: @VladD, понятно же, что придирка к самолету - это просто шутка. Вопрос так сформулирован.

Я бы задал его немного по другому

    Как лучше реализовать МОДЕЛЬ датчиков, которые ...

@Ульяна_Север, я бы сделал это в двух процессах. Один для программы сбора, упаковки и т.п. данных от датчиков, а второй собственно модель датчиков. Связь между  ними через общую память и пайп. 

В пайп датчики кидают свои события (номер_датчика:значение), а в sharedmemory записывают свои значения. Датчики вызываются неким диспетчером в определенные (для каждого м.б. свой) моменты времени.

И т.д. (места мало).